# Accessing data returned by Promise.all

Tags: angular, promise

In the service method below, I pass two parallel queries to the server using Promise.all. The results are returned and stored in the productCategoryData array. This array is logged to the console and the data is verified.

Service method

```
public getProductCategoryData() {
var productCategoryData = [];

return Promise.all([this.http.get(this.specialValueUrl), 
  this.http.get(this.applianceBrandUrl)])
.then(function(responses) {
  responses[0].toPromise().
    then(response => {
      let specialvalues: SpecialValue[] = response.json();
      productCategoryData[0] = specialvalues;
      // console.log(specialvalues)
    });

  responses[1].toPromise().
    then(response => {
      let applianceBrands: ApplianceBrand[] = response.json();
      productCategoryData[1] = applianceBrands;
      // console.log(applianceBrands)
    });        

  return productCategoryData;
})
  }
```

The productCategoryData array is then passed to the component where it is once again logged to the console. I then assign the data of the productCategoryData array to two arrays defined in the component: this.specialValues and this.applianceBrands. But they are undefined when logged to the console. I expect these arrays to have data.

Component method:

```
private getProductCategoryData() {
this.productCategoryService.getProductCategoryData()
.then(productCategoryData => {
  this.specialValues = productCategoryData[0];
  this.applianceBrands = productCategoryData[1];

  console.log('productCategory.Data = ', productCategoryData) //has data
  console.log('this.specialValues = ', this.specialValues) //undefined
  console.log('this.applianceBrands = ', this.applianceBrands) //undefined

});
  }
```

Comment: Is this AngularJS (Angular v1.x) or Angular (Angular v2+)? If AngularJS, please change the tag to `angularjs`.

Comment: It is Angular 2

Comment: OK, so I assume you mean `Component` method and not `Controller` method? And is it possible to use Observables instead of Promises here?

Comment: I changed it to component. I posted a question regarding Observables. Calls to the server using Observables are not arriving. Didn't get any correct response on that so I switched to Promise.

Comment: Can you provide a link to your post on Observables? That would be the better way to go since Http returns Observables.

Comment: Here is the link, Deborah: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45362013/angular-2-http-call-to-node-server-not-being-invoked

Comment: I replied. The original question most likely didn't get answered because it was tagged with `angularjs` which is for Angular v1 instead of `angular` which is for Angular v2+. I edited the tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is within the service. There are a couple things going on here.

- http.get returns an **Observable**. This must be subscribed to or converted to a **Promise**.
- Promise.all() will work normally for promises but will just pass in what it was given for anything else(like an Observable or variables etc.)

To fix this just convert your Observables (http.get()) to Promises and return that.

Due to you passing observables to promise.all() it made it seem like you needed to then convert the results themselves to promises in the call back but that is unnecessary.

this is all you need:

**service:**

```
public getProductCategoryData() {
   return Promise.all([this.http.get(this.specialValueUrl).toPromise(), 
    this.http.get(this.applianceBrandUrl).toPromise()])

}
```

**component:**

```
private getProductCategoryData() {
this.productCategoryService.getProductCategoryData()
  .then(productCategoryData => {
      this.specialValues = productCategoryData[0];
      this.applianceBrands = productCategoryData[1];

      console.log('productCategory.Data = ', productCategoryData) //has data
      console.log('this.specialValues = ', this.specialValues) //undefined
      console.log('this.applianceBrands = ', this.applianceBrands) //undefined

    });
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You are returning `productCategoryData` before you have assigned the asynchronous response to it via the two inner `then` callbacks.

Instead, convert to promises before applying `Promise.all` and then use `map` to apply the `json` method to the results:

```
return Promise.all([this.specialValueUrl, this.applianceBrandUrl].map(url =>
    this.http.get(url).toPromise()
).then(responses => responses.map(response => response.json()));
```